# Can I use inline CKEditor to change background color of div/section?

Tags: javascript, css, ckeditor

I have multiple instances of CKEditor's inline editors on a wall of text. I'd like to modify the background color functionality so that it changes its section's (can be `div` or `p`) background color instead. Is there a way to do this?

Example of my code:

```
<div id="editor">
  <div class="ckeditor-edit">This is a div section</div>
  <p class="ckeditor-edit">This one is a paragraph</p>
</div>
```

And I initialize CKEditor:

```
sections = $(".ckeditor-edit");
for (var i = 0; i < sections.length; i++) {
  CKEDITOR.inline(sections[i]);
}
```

I'm thinking I can use [CKEDITOR.dom.element's setStyle](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.element-method-setStyle) but I'm not sure where to start.

**EDIT**

So my code above will show 2 inline editors, one on `div` and one on `p`. What I want is when I select a background color on the editor for `div`, it should change the `div`'s background color. The background color for `p` should be controlled by the inline editor on `p`. The overall `div#editor` bg color should remain unchanged.

Comment: What color are you trying to change exactly? The div and paragraph on the page or something with the editor

Comment: @epascarello So for the inline editor initialized on the `div`, I want it to change only the `div` background color. And the editor on the `p` will do the same for the `p` (each section can have its own bg color)

Comment: Not sure how the bg property change on an individual editor would override the parent's color....

Comment: @epascarello Not sure I understand what you mean. I'm not trying to override the parent's color? Just the element CKEDITOR was initialized on.